# Warning: Unreachable code

Tags: solidity

I am getting the above error on line 91 - Trying to find out whether a certain address is present in an array through a for loop.

This is the function for convenience:

```
function isThisAddressStudent(address _studentAddress) public view returns (bool) {
        for(uint i; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {
            if(studentsArray[i] == _studentAddress) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            }
    }
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract MyContract {
    
    address payable public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    modifier isOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function deposit() public payable {
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    struct Questions {
        string[] Answers;
        uint correctAnswer;
    }

    struct AnswersStruct {
        string[] sAnswers;
    }

    struct Students {
        string Name;
        address StudentAddress;
    }
    
    address[] studentsArray;

    mapping(uint => mapping(string => address)) public students;
    mapping(uint => address) public studentsAddresses;
    mapping(address => uint) public studentsIds;
    mapping(uint => mapping(string => Questions)) public questions;
    mapping(uint => string) public idQuestions;
    mapping(uint => string[]) public questionAnswers;
    mapping(uint => uint) public correctAnswerMapping;
    
    // Add a student to be allowed to play the game
    function addStudent(uint _id, address _studentAddress, string memory _studentName) public isOwner {
        students[_id][_studentName] = _studentAddress;
        studentsAddresses[_id] = _studentAddress;
        studentsArray.push(_studentAddress);
    }

    // Adds question/answers to mappings
    function addQuestion(uint _qid, string memory _question, string memory _answerOne, string memory _answerTwo, string memory _answerThree, string memory _answerFour, uint _correctAnswer) public isOwner {
        Questions storage _q = questions[_qid][_question];
        _q.Answers = [_answerOne, _answerTwo, _answerThree, _answerFour];
        _q.correctAnswer = _correctAnswer;
        idQuestions[_qid] = _question;
        questionAnswers[_qid] = [_answerOne, _answerTwo, _answerThree, _answerFour];
        correctAnswerMapping[_qid] = _correctAnswer;
    }


    // Fetches Question String By It's ID in the 2nd Mapping
    function fetchQuestion(uint _qid) public view returns (string memory) {
        string memory veribeel;
        veribeel = idQuestions[_qid];
        return veribeel;
        
    }

    // Fetches All possible Answers of a certain question by ID
    function fetchAnswers(uint _id) public view returns (string[] memory) {
        string memory veribeel;
        string[] memory allAnswers;
        veribeel = idQuestions[_id];
        allAnswers = questionAnswers[_id];
        return allAnswers;
    }

    // Returns True/False based on string input if matches QuestionID's correctAnswer
    function answerQuestion(uint _id, uint _studentAnswer) public view returns (bool) {
        uint studentAnswer = correctAnswerMapping[_id];
        if (_studentAnswer == studentAnswer) {
            return true;
        }   else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function isThisAddressStudent(address _studentAddress) public view returns (bool) {
        for(uint i; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {
            if(studentsArray[i] == _studentAddress) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            }
    }
        
       

   



}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a loop there but your loop returns a value in all cases which means your loop always will run for just once. So, i++ will never run. (aka unreachable)

Your current code only checking if the given student address is the firsrt student or not. If it's not the first student it returns false. Instead, You should return false when your for loop ends.

Try this:

```
function isThisAddressStudent(address _studentAddress) public view returns (bool) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < studentsArray.length; i++)
            if(studentsArray[i] == _studentAddress)
                return true;
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Note: I removed curly brackets because you don't need curly brackets if there is only 1 line of code inside curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code because with the way that you have it, it will return right away in the first iteration.

Notice how you can move the `return false;` outside of the loop, in case it doesn't find it, it will get out of the loop and return false.

```js
function isThisAddressStudent(address _studentAddress) public view returns (bool) {
        for(uint i; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {
            if(studentsArray[i] == _studentAddress) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy!

So this definitely solved the error! Though now I'm facing another issue with this function/the addStudent function.

It seems like when u add the first student, it works perfectly (adding & reading). Though when i try the 2nd student, it starts bugging (Specfically getting TXID reverted on addStudent function)

Comment: Hi Ofir, I'm not sure if you are reading my answers because I was the one who replied first for both of your questions, still wondering if it worked with the other question. Because you didn't accept any of the answers. :)
Anyways, I went and ran your code in my remix. Adding/reading students worked perfectly fine. If you can provide more logs, we can help you more. Maybe provide us your testing parameters so we can reply the exact scenario that doesn't work.

Comment: hi, it works now! Not sure what i did wrong last night.

Also so sorry, just signed up 4 this platform so didn't know how to mark as resolved... I think it ended up not working but instead a friend came up with a different method that worked! Thanks a lot !